# Scala - Add element:MyType to Array = option[MyType] expected

Tags: scala

I have a `HashMap` which list all `MyType` element

```
var allMyType = new HashMap[String, MyType]()
```

And another `HashMap` which contain an `Array` of some `MyType` elements

```
var secondHashMap = new HashMap[Any, Array[MyType]]()
```

If I create a `secondHashMap` element with only one `MyType` element, I do :

```
secondHashMap.put(i, Array(allMyType.get(key)))
```

But, I have the error :

```
Type mismatch, expected : Array[Relation], actual : Array[Option[Relation]]
```

Changing the line

```
var secondHashMap = new HashMap[Any, Array[MyType]]()
```

To

```
var secondHashMap = new HashMap[Any, Array[Option[MyType]]]()
```

solved my problem but if I want to add a `MyType` element to the `Array` of an existing `secondHashMap` element  :

```
secondHashMap.put(563, secondHashMap.get(563)+=allMyType.get(key))
```

I obtain the error :

```
Type mismatch, expected : Array[Option[Relation]], actual : Option[Array[Option[Relation]]]
```

How can I do to solve this kind of problem?

I hope it was clear :s, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The get method returns an option of the value type as the lookup might fail. Here the signature:

```
  def get(key: A): Option[B]
```

You can get around this by calling getOrElse(defaultValue) on the option, or by using the apply method of Map which returns a B rather than an Option of B. However you'll have to make sure, that the key exists, because otherwise there will be an Exception.

So

```
secondHashMap.put(i, Array(allMyType.get(key)))
```

could become:

```
 secondHashMap.put(i, Array(allMyType(key)))
```